# Connecting JAVA with MySql using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connector

This is the code that i have tried. But everytime it shows the Error:Could not create connection to database server.What is the error in the code?Is the url syntax correct?

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Second {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "1234";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); 
            System.out.println("Connection is established.");
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've posted the StackTrace here.What is the Null pointer Exception I am getting?

```
Wed May 13 09:19:35 IST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at JDBC.Second.main(Second.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3005)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1916)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1845)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at mysql.connector.java@5.1.38/com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Are you running mysql on your machine?

Comment: Yes@Elliott Frisch

Comment: Could you provide stacktrace , easy to debug.

Comment: Try your current settings with [SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/#installation). Easiest way I know to validate the parameters you're using.

Comment: Everything looks good from coding side. Please post the stack trace , then only we can identify.

Comment: In the catch block , provide e.printStackTrace(); instead of sop. Provide that stack trace, then easy to find issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection url should be 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

Comment: Now it shows this error: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Comment: Which error, could you post stacktrace. Remove reconnect and try. If you get exception post it here

Comment: I get the same error as i posted above. Just the warning is removed this time @Vipul